# is it possible print element only when its detail band is the last on page?

Tags: jasper-reports

Is it possible, to get a condition, that I can print an element only when its detail band is the last on page in Jasper Reports?

We can have variable saying record number on the page. But how we get the calculated total record on each page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is done with the "reset type" on a variable

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jasperReport xmlns="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/jasperreport.xsd" name="report1" language="groovy" pageWidth="612" pageHeight="792" columnWidth="612" leftMargin="0" rightMargin="0" topMargin="10" bottomMargin="10" uuid="39852bd8-6125-4359-8d76-06927e7be492">
    <queryString>
        <![CDATA[SELECT ROWNUM N FROM dual  CONNECT BY LEVEL <= 200 ]]>
    </queryString>
    <field name="N" class="java.math.BigDecimal"/>
    <variable name="N_count_page" class="java.lang.Integer" resetType="Page" calculation="Count">
        <variableExpression><![CDATA[$F{N}]]></variableExpression>
    </variable>
    <variable name="N_count_report" class="java.lang.Integer" calculation="Count">
        <variableExpression><![CDATA[$F{N}]]></variableExpression>
    </variable>
    <title>
        <band height="20" splitType="Stretch">
            <textField>
                <reportElement uuid="93284d9f-1ee0-4a15-b227-31b55aa2e48b" x="0" y="0" width="376" height="20"/>
                <textElement textAlignment="Center">
                    <font size="14" isBold="true"/>
                </textElement>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA["Page Count"]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
        </band>
    </title>
    <columnHeader>
        <band height="20">
            <staticText>
                <reportElement uuid="a7113fdd-591b-4fee-9123-981ab75c6fa6" mode="Opaque" x="0" y="0" width="100" height="20" forecolor="#FFFFFF" backcolor="#000000"/>
                <textElement/>
                <text><![CDATA[N]]></text>
            </staticText>
        </band>
    </columnHeader>
    <detail>
        <band height="20">
            <textField>
                <reportElement uuid="54bac746-4efb-4412-81bc-b4ba807c60fd" x="0" y="0" width="100" height="20"/>
                <textElement/>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{N}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
        </band>
    </detail>
    <pageFooter>
        <band height="50">
            <staticText>
                <reportElement uuid="4c685263-0ef7-4a68-a328-39901ef2806f" x="0" y="0" width="100" height="20"/>
                <textElement textAlignment="Right"/>
                <text><![CDATA[Rows on page :]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <textField>
                <reportElement uuid="c65214f1-82dc-476a-8439-087854bbc5c6" x="100" y="0" width="100" height="20"/>
                <textElement/>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$V{N_count_page}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField>
                <reportElement uuid="48b37aff-b169-4ca2-b9dd-30c026988f68" x="289" y="30" width="80" height="20"/>
                <textElement textAlignment="Right"/>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA["Page "+$V{PAGE_NUMBER}+" of"]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField evaluationTime="Report">
                <reportElement uuid="983ccfed-d783-429e-bc6c-3fa488b2e106" x="369" y="30" width="40" height="20"/>
                <textElement/>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[" " + $V{PAGE_NUMBER}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
        </band>
    </pageFooter>
    <lastPageFooter>
        <band height="64">
            <staticText>
                <reportElement uuid="240e2f86-991a-4fc1-941b-56cc43b28c25" x="0" y="24" width="100" height="20"/>
                <textElement textAlignment="Right"/>
                <text><![CDATA[Rows on report :]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <textField>
                <reportElement uuid="718d4481-4716-4071-9989-27d5119fb428" x="100" y="24" width="100" height="20"/>
                <textElement/>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$V{N_count_report}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField evaluationTime="Report">
                <reportElement uuid="f03359be-3bbe-4da8-9bd8-ac024aa6f289" x="369" y="44" width="40" height="20"/>
                <textElement/>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[" " + $V{PAGE_NUMBER}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField>
                <reportElement uuid="ad4aa2c0-9ad8-4892-a16f-0bb584c93916" x="289" y="44" width="80" height="20"/>
                <textElement textAlignment="Right"/>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA["Page "+$V{PAGE_NUMBER}+" of"]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement uuid="b4bdd29a-4ef9-46cc-a57a-df7577bdd73f" x="0" y="0" width="100" height="20"/>
                <textElement textAlignment="Right"/>
                <text><![CDATA[Rows on page :]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <textField>
                <reportElement uuid="39952747-170c-4747-8e2c-0e12ab608ae9" x="100" y="0" width="100" height="20"/>
                <textElement/>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$V{N_count_page}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
        </band>
    </lastPageFooter>
</jasperReport>
```

Comment: This answer is not answering the question. Question was how to achieve that band element is printed when it is last on each page. And not on last page only.

Comment: OK then you would have a variable with Calculation of "count" reset type type ="page"  and put that in your page footer band