# Print when last row on table Jasper report

Tags: jasper-reports

I have a report that needs to have an image printed only in the **last row** of the table of each page.
How can I create my **print when expression**?

Edit:

Sorry for my poor exemple.

until now, i created this variable

```
<variable name="rowsOnPage" class="java.lang.Integer">
        <variableExpression><![CDATA[$V{rowsOnPage} + 1]]></variableExpression>
        <initialValueExpression><![CDATA[0]]></initialValueExpression>
</variable>
```

and i try this print when expression:

```
$V{rowsOnPage} == $V{REPORT_COUNT}
```

But this expression print the image in each row of table.

Comment: You need to give us a small example, what kind of table (jr:table?), try to put together a [mcve] for this question posting jrxml. I don't think this is directly possibile, it will be to late in report process to evaluate if last row in a page, but probably there is a work around to get the image where you like it to be.

Comment: You can look at [Print When Expression to print only the last element in the group](http://stackoverflow.com/q/22988553/876298) & [is it possible print element only when its detail band is the last on page?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/13047905/876298)  posts. This trick can help you too: [Compare current page number with last page number](http://stackoverflow.com/q/5138360/876298)

Comment: @PetterFriberg Sorry for my poor exemple and my poor english, i'm very starters with programmation and google translator help with english.

Comment: And thank you for this exemple @AlexK, i used the secound link that talk about the resource "resetType=page" and this work for me!

Comment: It will be great if you post your solution as an answer. You are welcome :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Petter says, providing an example of what you've tried and how close you've got so far would be helpful.

In the meantime my suggestion is that you add a max rowcount value to your SQL and return this as field in your JRXML as e.g. maxRowNum. With this you could then use a printWhen at the point when `$V{REPORT_COUNT} == $F{maxRowNum}`

This assumes you have access to the SQL part of your code and can play with this.

Comment: It can be a report based on non-sql based datasource

Comment: Fingers crossed it's not. Without any code we're all guessing anyway :-)

Comment: The question is "only in the last row of the table of **each** page", this I guess is our main problem, hence maxRowNum would solve it only on last page

Comment: Thanks for the help, I have access to SQL but returning the total number of lines would not be useful because the image needs to be printed at the end of each page

Comment: Sorry, I misread about it being per page before. Are you able to restrict the number of rows per page to e.g. 25, then just print the image at every 25th row AND the final row?