# How to print text for each iteration in the detail except for the last one?

Tags: jasper-reports

I have a subreport that iterates names. I want to print a the text "or" on every loop, except for the last one. Right now I'm doing a suggested solution [in this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44034002/print-when-last-row-on-table-jasper-report), but it still prints in the last iterate.

Here is a sample of what I have right now:

[image: Current]

There is still an extra **or** in the end of the subreport.

Current subreport source code I have right now:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!-- Created with Jaspersoft Studio version 6.5.1.final using JasperReports Library version 6.5.1  -->
<jasperReport xmlns="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/jasperreport.xsd" name="paiwi-signatories-name-only-subreport" pageWidth="595" pageHeight="842" columnWidth="555" leftMargin="20" rightMargin="20" topMargin="20" bottomMargin="20" uuid="8f474d5a-0cca-4c5f-807e-71af8848276f">
    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.data.defaultdataadapter" value="signatoryJSON"/>
    <queryString language="json">
        <![CDATA[signatoryNames]]>
    </queryString>
    <field name="name" class="java.lang.String">
        <fieldDescription><![CDATA[name]]></fieldDescription>
    </field>
    <field name="address" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <variable name="signatoryCurrentCount" class="java.lang.Integer" resetType="None">
        <variableExpression><![CDATA[$V{nameGroup_COUNT}]]></variableExpression>
    </variable>
    <group name="nameGroup">
        <groupExpression><![CDATA[$F{name}]]></groupExpression>
    </group>
    <detail>
        <band height="36" splitType="Stretch">
            <textField isBlankWhenNull="true">
                <reportElement positionType="Float" x="-20" y="-20" width="260" height="20" uuid="220a59b9-595b-4149-badd-f4a1ecff36c5"/>
                <textElement>
                    <font fontName="Times New Roman" size="12"/>
                </textElement>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{name}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField evaluationTime="Auto" isBlankWhenNull="true">
                <reportElement positionType="Float" x="0" y="0" width="100" height="20" isRemoveLineWhenBlank="true" uuid="afda4fcc-78fc-46f9-8c5c-2e0c4f04dfa5"/>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$V{signatoryCurrentCount}.equals($V{nameGroup_COUNT}) ? "or" : ""]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
        </band>
    </detail>
</jasperReport>
```

How can I avoid to print the last textField after last record?

Answer (score 2):

You can try a simple thing, put the 2 variables in your report, I think you already know how many pages your report will contain, and then change the `printWhenExpression` statement to the value of your page, for example your report contains 20 pages, then in your variable change the print condition to `PAGE_NUMBER==20` and `PAGE_NUMBER < 20` for the other one.
Good luck.

Answer (score 1):

If you like to leverage `evalutationTime="Auto"`

> Variables will be evaluated at a time corresponding to their reset type

<sup>From [EvaluationTimeEnum](http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/api/net/sf/jasperreports/engine/type/EvaluationTimeEnum.html#AUTO)</sup>

You need 2 variables with different **reset** time. Adapting to your example a solution can be:

Setting your `signatoryCurrentCount` to the `REPORT_COUNT` but reseting everytime your group change (hence on every record in your example)

```
<variable name="signatoryCurrentCount" class="java.lang.Integer" resetType="Group" resetGroup="nameGroup">
    <variableExpression><![CDATA[$V{REPORT_COUNT}]]></variableExpression>
</variable>
```

Then you compare this with the built in variable `$V{REPORT_COUNT}` that have reset type report

```
<textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$V{signatoryCurrentCount}<$V{REPORT_COUNT} ? "or" : ""]]></textFieldExpression>
```

To understand the expression with reset type "Auto", the `signatoryCurrentCount` will have 1,2,3 (reset's at group) and `$V{REPORT_COUNT}` always 3 (reset at report).

## Full Example

**jrxml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jasperReport xmlns="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/jasperreport.xsd" name="paiwi-signatories-name-only-subreport" pageWidth="595" pageHeight="842" columnWidth="555" leftMargin="20" rightMargin="20" topMargin="20" bottomMargin="20" uuid="8f474d5a-0cca-4c5f-807e-71af8848276f">
    <queryString language="json">
        <![CDATA[signatoryNames]]>
    </queryString>
    <field name="name" class="java.lang.String">
        <fieldDescription><![CDATA[name]]></fieldDescription>
    </field>
    <field name="address" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <variable name="signatoryCurrentCount" class="java.lang.Integer" resetType="Group" resetGroup="nameGroup">
        <variableExpression><![CDATA[$V{REPORT_COUNT}]]></variableExpression>
    </variable>
    <group name="nameGroup">
        <groupExpression><![CDATA[$F{name}]]></groupExpression>
    </group>
    <detail>
        <band height="36" splitType="Stretch">
            <textField isBlankWhenNull="true">
                <reportElement positionType="Float" x="-20" y="-20" width="260" height="20" uuid="220a59b9-595b-4149-badd-f4a1ecff36c5"/>
                <textElement>
                    <font fontName="Times New Roman" size="12"/>
                </textElement>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{name}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField evaluationTime="Auto" isBlankWhenNull="true">
                <reportElement positionType="Float" x="0" y="0" width="100" height="20" isRemoveLineWhenBlank="true" uuid="afda4fcc-78fc-46f9-8c5c-2e0c4f04dfa5"/>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$V{signatoryCurrentCount}<$V{REPORT_COUNT} ? "or" : ""]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
        </band>
    </detail>
</jasperReport>
```

**output**

[image: result]

> **Do note:** using evaluationTime="Auto" is resource intensive for jasper report, in most cases I would suggest that users pass in datasource the totale number of records, the report will be generated faster.

Comment: Hi @PetterFriberg, thanks for helping out as always. I have thought of the same, like I have two choices, either use an available option inside JasperReport (which is this evaluationTime, thanks for giving me this information) or, just pass the total number of records in the data source. which I can use simply by getting the length of the array in the Java program. I'll update you within the day about this. =)